# GCD stopping async queues from proceeding

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, afnetworking

I'm downloading a file using `AFHTTPRequestOperation` from the awesome [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/).

I'm downloading large zip files, which need to be unzipped once the download is finished. But since the `AFHTTPRequestOperation`'s completion block happens on the main thread, and these are relatively large files, I need to to the unzipping on a background thread, which I've implemented with GCD.

But the unzipping in this background thread can go wrong and if that's the case I need to be able to stop the thread from continuing... Is there a way to do it with GCD or do I have to put everything in the enormous body of an `if` statement?

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *theOperation, id responseObject){

    NSLog(@"*** TP DOWNLOADER: Finished downloading");

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{

        //Unzip the file:
        ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

        BOOL unzipOpenFileSuccessful = [za UnzipOpenFile:operation.targetPath Password:@"thepassword"];
        if(!unzipOpenFileSuccessful){

            NSLog(@"Problems unzipping!");

            //should return here and not keep doing work!
        }

        //keep doing work... 

    });
];
```

Comment: As stated by Wade just use a `return;` statement if it's not successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just "return" if an error occurs.